# How to update multiple objects in a single collection of mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have one collection in mongodb as given below -

```
[
 {
  id: "1",
  itemName: "pen",
  quantity: 10
 },
 {
  id: "2",
  itemName: "notebook",
  quantity: 20
 },
 {
  id: "3",
  itemName: "book",
  quantity: 30
 }
]
```

I have to update this collection in one go. From UI I am getting the request array as -

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "quantity": 12
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "quantity": 13
 }
]
```

I need to update the corresponding objects. I can run it in a for loop and using

> db.collection.update()

I can update it. But is there any way to pass the whole array to update the corresponding objects in one go?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124496/mongo-bulk-find-and-update-matched-documents-field-in-single-query