# MongoDB bulk update with external data

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection

```
[
{"_id":1,"data" :[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}] },
{"_id":2,"data" :[{"a":1},{"b":2}]  },
{"_id":3,"data":[{"c":3},1,2,3]},
{"_id":4,"data":[{"b":1},{"d":2},{"c":3}]},
{"_id":5,"data":[{"c":2},{"a":3}]},
{"_id":6,"data":[0,2,3]},
{"_id":7,"data":[{"b":4},{"c":3}]}
]
```

I also have the following update set that I want to use to update the data arrays in my collection

```
[
{"id":1,"old":{"c":3}, "new":{"v":2}},
{"id":4, "old":{"b":1},"new":{"v":3}},
{"id":5, "old":{"a":3},"new":{"v":3}},
{"id":7, "old":{"c":2},"new":{"v":3}}
]
```

For each of these datapoints, If old is found in the data array of the document with "_id" = "id"
I want to replace it with the new value. The output should look like this:

```
[
{"_id":1,"data" :[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"v":2}] },
{"_id":2,"data" :[{"a":1},{"b":2}]  },
{"_id":3,"data":[{"c":3},1,2,3]},
{"_id":4,"data":[{"v":3},{"d":2},{"c":3}]},
{"_id":5,"data":[{"c":2},{"v":3}]},
{"_id":6,"data":[0,2,3]},
{"_id":7,"data":[{"b":4},{"c":3}]}
]
```

My solution so far has been to iterate through the update set and performing the following update query for each datapoint:

```
myCollection.update({"_id":id,"data":old},{"$set":{"data.$":new}})
```

Is there a way to perform all updates at once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo bulk find and update matched documents field in single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124496/mongo-bulk-find-and-update-matched-documents-field-in-single-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a similar import method from csv. I do a find and loop through the data to compare and build an update array. that is then fed into the bulkWrite() method.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/

edit-

Because you are doing each based on it's own criteria you will have to do many updateOne()'s in a bulkwrite. So it'll be something like below.

i am used to javascript so the example is in that rather than shell. But you should get the idea how to build the object.

```
let mongoUpdates = []
let newStuff = [
{"id":1,"old":{"c":3}, "new":{"v":2}},
{"id":4, "old":{"b":1},"new":{"v":3}},
{"id":5, "old":{"a":3},"new":{"v":3}},
{"id":7, "old":{"c":2},"new":{"v":3}}
]

mongoUpdates = newStuff.map(item => {
  return {
    updateOne: {
      "filter": {
        _id: item.id,
        date: item.old
      },
      "update": { $set: { "data.$" : item.new } }
    }
  }
})

collection.bulkWrite(mongoUpdates)
```

So i am using:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/
For each item to find and set the update appropriatly

then [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)
to find the position of the "old" in the array then place the "new" over it

then calling the bulk on the array than contains an updateOne for each item.

This code is untested but should get you close to where you need to be.