# MongoDB - Get IDs of inserted and existing documents after "Insert if not exist" operation on multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to insert multiple documents if they don't already exist, but the important thing is that in the query results I need to have IDs of both the inserted and already existing items.

I'm trying with the following `bulkWrite` operation:

```
// external_id is a unique id other than the mongo _id
let items = [
   {external_id: 123, name: "John"},
   {external_id: 456, name: "Mike"},
   {external_id: 789, name: "Joseph"}
];
db.collection("my_collection")
  .bulkWrite(
    items.map((item) => {
      return {
        updateOne: {
          filter: { external_id: item.external_id },
          update: { $setOnInsert: item},
          upsert: true,
        },
      };
    })
  );
```

The problem is that the `BulkWriteResult` return only the `_id` of the inserted items in `upsertedIds`, while for the existing items return only the `nMatched` number.

The other solution I have think about is to make (1) a `find` over an array of ids, (2) check the results for the ones already existing, and (3) then `insertMany` for the new ones:

```
 let ids = [123, 456, 789];
 let items = [
   {external_id: 123, name: "John"},
   {external_id: 456, name: "Mike"},
   {external_id: 789, name: "Joseph"}
 ];

 // STEP 1: Find alredy existings items
 db.collection("my_collection")
  .find({ external_id: { $in: ids } })
  .toArray(function (err, existingItems) {
     // If John already exist
     // existingItems = [{_id: ObjectId, external_id: 123, name: "John"}]

     // STEP 2: Check which item has to be created
     let itemsToBeCreated = items.filter((item) =>
       !existingItems.some((ex) => ex.external_id === item.external_id)
     );

     // STEP 3: Insert new items
     db.collection("my_collection")     
       .insertMany(itemsToBeCreated, function (err, result) {          
         // FINALLY HERE I GET ALL THE IDs OF THE EXISTING AND INSERTED ITEMS
     });
  });
```

With this solution I'm concerned about performance, because these operations are fired 100K times a day for 10 items each,  and about 90% of the times the items are new. So 900K new items and 100K already existing.

I would like to know if there is a better way of achieving this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get an option to get IDs of modified documents?

Comment: findAndModify with upsert:true  always return the document _id for updated & inserted

Comment: maybe you can you use [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

Comment: Is there any option to do it with bulkwrite? @Catalin

Comment: @R2D2 With bulkwrite permitted operations only include insert, update, delete one and many. How can findAndModify be used? I don't want to iterate over the data and insert/update one by one.